# Matrix from scaled vectors notation

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, hadamard-product

I'm trying to find a concise way to notate the following operation:

$$
\vec{a}^T \space \text{(Operator)} \space \vec{b} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
a_1 \vec{b} \space \dots \space a_N \vec{b}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

for my personal work I have been using the Hadamard product ($\circ$) for (Operator), but I don't think that is correct. Is there a standard notation to write this?

Comment: How about $\,ba^T\,$ i.e the regular matrix product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operation is [tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product) $\otimes$ (or it's sometimes called outer product):
$$
\vec b\otimes\vec a = \begin{pmatrix}
a_1b_1&\cdots &a_nb_1\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_1 b_n& \ldots& a_nb_n
\end{pmatrix}
$$